# Disposing 2nd Time Doesn't Dispose Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose

I use this method to close forms according to their Id, but if I open a form with Id 2, close it once, it works fine, but if I open a form again with Id 2, it doesn't close the form (the form just stays on the screen).  I have no idea what is going on and desperately need help.  Thanks!

```
public void OutsideClose(long Id)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action<long>(OutsideClose), Id);
    }
    else
    {
        var FormToClose = ListForms.Find(a=> a.Id == Id);
        if(FormToClose != null)
        {
            FormToClose.Dispose();
            OpenForms.Remove(Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid code - you look like you're removing the *ID* rather than the form - and you don't have a semi-colon after the Remove call. Please provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem - it'll be much easier to help you then.

Comment: added the semicolon, sorry on poor transcription, i also edited the code because you're right again, there are actually 2 lists, ListForms contains forms, OpenForms contains Id's

Comment: Hey man, you asked basically the same question right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233008/invoking-something-twice-leads-to-protected-override-void-dispose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am dumb!
I was disposing the form, but I wasn't removing it from the list.  Now I added a line of code to do that and now it's fixed.

Edit: Thanks Jon for making me look closer at the code (especially the two lists)